# Why can't I simulate auto-completion with '\t' in busybox

Tags: c, linux, shell, autocomplete, busybox

I want to use "yp\t\n\0" to run “ypdomainname” command by exploiting auto-completion in busybox, but it failed. my code and result are below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define DEFAULT_BUSYBOX_PATH "/bin/busybox"
#define MAX_BUF 1000

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    FILE *file;
    int status;

    if(pipe(fd) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe error!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe error!\n");
    }else if(pid == 0){     //child
        close(fd[1]);

        int fd_output;
        fd_output = open("result", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 777);

        if(fd_output != STDOUT_FILENO){
            if(dup2(fd_output, STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO)
                fprintf(stderr, "dup2 error to stdout\n");
        }

        if(fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO){
            if(dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
                fprintf(stderr, "dup2 error to stdin\n");
        }
        execl(DEFAULT_BUSYBOX_PATH, DEFAULT_BUSYBOX_PATH, "ash", NULL);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd_output);
        return 0;
    }else{                  //parent
        close(fd[0]);

        char buf[MAX_BUF] = "yp";
        buf[2] = '\t';
        buf[3] = '\n';
        buf[4] = '\0';

        write(fd[1], buf, strlen(buf));

        close(fd[1]);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

[Result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btSb7.jpg)

What makes me confused is that the character is not changed in function `lineedit_read_key()` in file lineedit.c and it will run the function `input_tab()` when the character is '\t'.
[input_tab will be executed when character is '\t'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7WES.png)

Recently, i took some time to learn about terminal to simulate auto-completion, but i still failed. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pty.h>

#define DEFAULT_BUSYBOX_PATH "/bin/busybox"
#define MAX_BUF 1000
#define BUFFSIZE 512

typedef void Sigfunc(int);

static void sig_term(int);
static volatile sig_atomic_t sigcaught;

ssize_t writen(int fd, const void *ptr, size_t n){
    size_t nleft;
    ssize_t nwritten;

    nleft = n;
    while(nleft > 0){
        if((nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0){
            if(nleft == n){
                return(-1); 
            }else{
                break; 
            }
        }else if(nwritten == 0) {
            break;
        }
        nleft -= nwritten;
        ptr += nwritten;
    }
    return(n - nleft);
}

Sigfunc *signal_intr(int signo, Sigfunc *func){
    struct sigaction act;
    struct sigaction oact;

    act.sa_handler = func;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
#ifdef  SA_INTERRUPT
    act.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
#endif
    if (sigaction(signo, &act, &oact) < 0)
        return(SIG_ERR);
    return(oact.sa_handler);
}

int ptym_open(char *pts_name, int pts_namesz)
{
    char ptr[50];
    int fdm;
    int err;

    if((fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR)) < 0){
        return(-1);
    }   
    if(grantpt(fdm) < 0){ 
        goto errout;
    }           
    if(unlockpt(fdm) < 0){  
        goto errout;
    }       

    if(ptsname_r(fdm, ptr, 50) != 0){
        goto errout;
    }

    strncpy(pts_name, ptr, pts_namesz);
    pts_name[pts_namesz - 1] = '\0';
    return(fdm);            /* return fd of master */
errout:
    err = errno;
    close(fdm);
    errno = err;
    return(-1);
}

int ptys_open(char *pts_name){
    int fds;

    if((fds = open(pts_name, O_RDWR)) < 0)
        return(-1);

    return(fds);
}

pid_t pty_fork(int *ptrfdm, char *slave_name, int slave_namesz, const struct termios *slave_termios, const struct winsize *slave_winsize){
    int     fdm, fds;
    pid_t   pid;
    char    pts_name[20];

    if((fdm = ptym_open(pts_name, sizeof(pts_name))) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open master pty: %s, error %d", pts_name, fdm);
    }   

    if(slave_name != NULL) {
        strncpy(slave_name, pts_name, slave_namesz);
        slave_name[slave_namesz - 1] = '\0';
    }

    if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        return(-1);
    }else if (pid == 0) {       /* child */
        if(setsid() < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "setsid error");
        }

        if((fds = ptys_open(pts_name)) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "can't open slave pty");
        }
        close(fdm);     

        if(slave_termios != NULL) {
            if (tcsetattr(fds, TCSANOW, slave_termios) < 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "tcsetattr error on slave pty");
        }
        if(slave_winsize != NULL) {
            if (ioctl(fds, TIOCSWINSZ, slave_winsize) < 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "TIOCSWINSZ error on slave pty");
        }

        if(dup2(fds, STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO){
            fprintf(stderr, "dup2 error to stdin");
        }
        if(dup2(fds, STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO){
            fprintf(stderr, "dup2 error to stdout");
        }
        if(dup2(fds, STDERR_FILENO) != STDERR_FILENO){
            fprintf(stderr, "dup2 error to stderr");
        }
        if(fds != STDIN_FILENO && fds != STDOUT_FILENO && fds != STDERR_FILENO){
            close(fds);
        }
        return(0);      
    } else {                    /* parent */
        *ptrfdm = fdm;  
        return(pid);    
    }
}

void loop(int ptym, int ignoreeof)
{
    pid_t   child;
    int     nread;
    char    buf[BUFFSIZE];

    if((child = fork()) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error");
    }else if(child == 0) {  
        /*for ( ; ; ){
            if((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "read error from stdin");
            }else if(nread == 0){
                break;
            }

            if(writen(ptym, buf, nread) != nread)
                fprintf(stderr, "writen error to master pty");
        }*/
        char *temp_buf = "yp\t\n";
        if(writen(ptym, temp_buf, strlen(temp_buf)) != strlen(temp_buf)){
            fprintf(stderr, "writen error to master pty");
        }

        if(ignoreeof == 0){
            kill(getppid(), SIGTERM);
        }

        exit(0);
    }

    if (signal_intr(SIGTERM, sig_term) == SIG_ERR)
        fprintf(stderr, "signal_intr error for SIGTERM");

    for( ; ; ){
        if ((nread = read(ptym, buf, BUFFSIZE)) <= 0){

        }
        //printf("nread = %d\n", nread);
        if (writen(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nread) != nread){
            fprintf(stderr, "writen error to stdout");
        }
    }

    if (sigcaught == 0){
        printf("sigcaught == 0 and kill child\n");
        kill(child, SIGTERM);
    }   
}

static void sig_term(int signo)
{
    sigcaught = 1;      
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    FILE *file;
    int status;
    int fdm;
    int ignoreeof;
    char slave_name[40];
    struct termios orig_termios;
    struct winsize size;

    pid = pty_fork(&fdm, slave_name, sizeof(slave_name), &orig_termios, &size);
    if(pid < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error!\n");
    }else if(pid == 0){  //child
        if(execl(DEFAULT_BUSYBOX_PATH, DEFAULT_BUSYBOX_PATH, "ash", NULL) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "can't execute: %s", DEFAULT_BUSYBOX_PATH);
        }
        /*if(execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "can't execute: %s", argv[1]);
        }*/
    }

    loop(fdm, ignoreeof);
}
```

like the result of my first try, the result is: ash: yp: not found.

Comment: FYI, when posting questions, do not put pictures of code.  Nothing in your pictures could not have been pasted in the question.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because a pipe is not a terminal. Many programs will use [`isatty(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) and alike to detect if the standard input is connected to a terminal and adjust their behaviour depending on the result.

What you can do is to open a pseudo terminal pair using [`openpty(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html) and run the command with the slave duplicated to its standard input, output and error descriptors, and using the master to communicate with it. Unfortunately I have no time right now writing a full solution as it is rather intricate; I've done it ever in Python and it was tricky even there.

Comment: Do you mean that the right input and output of busybox is terminal and what i should do is to figure out which role terminal take?

Comment: @gc12138 no that's figured out but you need to use I/O multiplexing with select to read from and write to the pseudoterminal which is much more complex than piping to one side of the program only... this just in case it behaves differently if the *output* is not a terminal.

Comment: Maybe i should learn more about terminal. Thank you very much anyway!